# Policy on multi part answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

B"H

One has the option to add multiple answers to the same question.

The question now is, that there is a character limit for each answer.

If one has a very detailed answer that would best be answered by going beyond that limit, is one allowed to make a "part 2" answer?

Specifically thinking about this answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/131740/31763 which could have the potential to expand, with new points being added.

Answer (score 2):

The character limit for answers is a deliberate part of the design for Stack Exchange. The model of this site depends on all posts being subject to review by the community for fit, quality, content, etc. The longer a post is, the less amenable it is to review; the character limit is at the outside edge of plausibility for meaningful review by the crowd.

If you're bumping up against the character limit, that's a signal that your post is too long to be an answer that's likely to be useful to the asker and maintainable by the community. Rather than look for a way to circumvent the limit, consider editing your post to ensure that it's only as long as necessary to directly address the question at hand.

In the case of the answer you point to, it seems that you're using the answer as a way to publish a complete blow-by-blow transcript of an interview you conducted. Clearly, the log of who said what when is not essential to directly addressing the question, and probably, much of the content of the interview is also not essential for this purpose. I understand that you want to preserve the interview itself, verbatim, for posterity. I encourage you to do so on a platform that is better-suited for publishing such documents, and to write an answer here that links to that and provides an on-point answer to the question at hand based on it.

Comment: Hi "Clearly, the log of who said what when is not essential to directly addressing the question" not necessarily, in order to properly understand what he is saying one needs the context. So many times people say not to outsource content. What if the link goes down,? Then no one will be able to see the sources. What free hosting platform with unlimited bandwidth and uptime is there?

Comment: All of the information necessary to directly address the question at hand should be in the answer post. If the question is too complex to address directly without quoting more than ten pages of interview transcript verbatim, then I recommend flagging it for closure as "Too Broad."

Comment: Most of that interview verbatim is him providing sources, which wouldn't make sense without the context. I also don't understand his underlying reasoning and not able to properly summarize it

Comment: If you don't understand how the material addresses the question, it's going to be difficult-to-impossible for you to write an answer based on it that helps anyone else understand how to resolve the question. It's also difficult to expect the community to help maintain and improve the post. It would be best to publish material you don't understand but think is valuable to expose to the world on a platform best-suited for that, and to write answers that you do understand here.

Comment: Is understanding a condition of the TOS?

Comment: @YakkOv Of course not. We don't and can't have any rules that address the internal state of someone's mind. I'm giving you advice based on your description of your relationship to this material. Your post will be evaluated and maintained by community members based on its own fitness, quality, content, etc. Most importantly, how *helpful it is to people interested in the question* depends on what's in it and how it's written. If you want it to be maximally helpful and also to get maximal positive attention, my *recommendation* is to stick to writing about what you understand.

Comment: ... more to the point of this Meta post: No, the fact that you don't understand the material well enough to extract a direct answer to the question of reasonable length out of it is not a good justification for circumventing the built-in limit on post length.